# How can I add containers that seem to float over a textured background in wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I would like my wordpress site to show the different excerpts of text in separate containers that seem to float on top of a textured background, as in the following website: http://www.sopcial.com/

I would also like this effect in my posts, so that the post itself is in one container and the sidebar with related posts is in a different container. Is that possible?

I tried using the code provided by jmoore009 (except I changed the width to 1000px), but somehow the height of the container changes (or it looks like that to me). Besides, adding this code brings up a container in the header and another one in the footer... How can I erase them?

The link is  http://www.planificamostuviaje.com

Thank you

Comment: The code on that site looks pretty straightforward, clean, and accessible to anyone. What are you having a problem with implementing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `box-shadow` to give it the appearance that the container is sitting on top of the background:

```
<div class="container content-box"></div>
```

```
.content-box{
   background: #FFF;
   width: 200px;
   margin: auto;
   padding: 20px;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
   border-radius: 3px;
   -moz-box-sizing:border-box; //add to fix padding 
   -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
   box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/acv8evt5/2/)

Comment: Thanks! This gave me the desired effect. However, the height of my container has completely changed. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: @SusanaÁvila yeah probably because of the padding which adds to the height/width. You dont have to add it if you dont want (although it really helps space things out) but if you do use it add `box-sizing: border-box`. I updated my answer to reflect this. Let me know if that's the issue

Comment: Thanks, but nothing changed after adding this :(

Comment: Do you have a link? Or can you recreate the issue in a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: jmore009 - I just edited the question including the link. Thank you!

Comment: @SusanaÁvila thanks, instead of just adding those styles to `.container` I would create a new class and add that class to the container you want to target. Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you! I will try that as soon as I figure out how to do it - I understand this is not the place to ask beginner questions.

Comment: @SusanaÁvila it's absolutely a place to ask all questions, no matter how beginner they are. Ask away

Comment: really??? Awesome! Thank you so much for taking the time out of your busy schedule to help me out! I actually have two questions:

Comment: 1- how do I create a class and add the class to the container? I'm guessing I need to add code to style.ccs but I have no clue on how to call it from a specific part of the website

Comment: 2- How can I create different containers to "box" different parts of the page? For example, I would like to have a container for the post, a different container for the sidebar, and a different container for comments. Please let me know if I should move this discussion to chat, so as to avoid extending the comments thread. Thanks

Comment: You dont have enough rep so it wont let me move this to chat. You create a class just by typing **ANY name** with a `.` in front, like so:  `.someclassname` in your  css file. then you can access it simply by adding `class` to any element in your HTML file like this: `<div class="someclassname"></div>` or `<p class="someclassname"></p>` etc. You can add multiple classes to the same element by using a space like this: `<div class="someclassname anotherclassname"></div>` So thats what i suggest you do here. Create a new class and add it to the elements you want it to apply to. Make sense?

Comment: Cannot tell you how happy I am. This opens up a new world of possibilities! I am forever grateful! Not able to vote your answer as I do not have enough reputation, but I will definitely come back when I do.